# Boost Log Run Time Error

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am trying to following this boost tutorial for its log lib [Boost Log tutorial](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html). Using the same code, as

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

The code can be successfully compiled as expected. However, when I run the code, a run-time error pop up as:[Entry Point Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCaLR.jpg). The error message reads as:

> The procedure entry point AcquireSRWLockShared could not be located in
>   the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.

I used Boost lib for other purpose, like generating random numbers, so I guess the library itself is properly installed.

Can anyone help me with this please? Thank you.

Comment: Please copy the error into your question, for searchability purposes.

Comment: MSDN for that error: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142606, please check your boost installation.

Comment: It sounds like you're using dynamic linking and the `boost` DLLs are not in  the `PATH`

Comment: @kenba It's unlikely that the error is caused by something in PATH, since I used Boost for other purposes already. If there is something run, my other code wouldn't be running either. Please let me know if I missed anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your Boost libraries were built for Windows Vista and later while you are running an older Windows version.

You need to rebuild Boost for Windows XP. To do that you need to add `define=BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0501` to the `b2` command line when building Boost and also define this macro similarly when building your code as well.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Semashev. However, it's unlikely that the issue is with older versions of Windows. My machine is running on Windows XP, and the Boost Library was built on this very same machine. In addition, I have used Boost Library in the past for other purposes, such as generating random numbers and converting data types as well as matrix calculations.

Comment: You can build programs for newer Windows on Windows XP, and by default recent Boost compiles for Windows Vista, if the compiler supports it. Some libraries may not use APIs from Windows Vista, others do - that's why you could have used some libraries before. So I stand by my advice.

Comment: Thanks again @Andrey Semashev. My machine is on Windows XP, and I always build and run program on this machine. That's why I am not so convinced. Please do let me know if I misunderstood your advice. Thanks.